# LINQ returns Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am working now sometime with like but have a weard error and can't find the reason why.

I have a List which contains several other lists and I select with

```
var images_tags = posts.Select(x => x.images.Select(y => y.tags));
```

the correct list which is also being returned.
Than I want to know how many returns I have so I do a simple

```
int count = images_tags.Count();
```

This results everytime in a error

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
```

The images_tags is a List<> but seems not to be able to return any value however there are 2 records in....

What do I miss....

Comment: There is probably a `post` that has a null `.images` property.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the concept of Linq. Linq uses **lazy evaluation**. That means `posts.Select(...)` just returns an **Enumerable** (which just provides an iterator) and does not yet execute the query. The query in `posts.Select(...)` will actually be executed/evaluated at the time when you do `images_tags.Count()`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the count of all tags in all images in all posts? Also ensure that none of the posts are null and that none of the posts have a null `images` member and that none of the images have a null `tags` member.

Comment: Technically, a null `.tags` wouldn't cause anything to fail here.  But then again, even if it worked, this wouldn't do anything different than `image_tags.Count()`, so it's probably not what was intended.

Comment: Set the debugger to break on all exceptions. Investigate where the error occurred instead of staring at the code for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but above I understand and know. What I need to know is very simple out Enumerable Select the return in the Count, I do know he looks exec on .Count() and also even if there is a null I should be able to get that "null" instead of an error without using exceptions and error handler.

Comment: You're just guessing. Find out for sure. It is not hard.

Comment: Yes I know for sure as I debug through it and get the error on this